# Pass JSON result from AJAX to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I am querying a fuseki server using AJAX and the result that I am getting is a JSON object.

I would like to use pagination to go through the result with a limit of records per page. I have tried to send the JSON object to a div in the html file but it is not working. Is there a workaround this? Here is my code:

```js
function myCallBack2(data) {
  var all_results = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < data.results.bindings.length; i++) {
    var bc = '';
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      bc = '#b8cddb';
    } else {
      bc = '#f2f5f7';
    }
    all_results += '<div class="all_results" style="background-color:' + bc + '">';
    for (var j = 0; j < data.head.vars.length; j++) {
      var text = data.results.bindings[i][data.head.vars[j]].value;
      var type = data.results.bindings[i][data.head.vars[j]].type;
      all_results += '<div class="result_row">';
      if (type == ('literal')) {
        all_results += '<p> ' + data.head.vars[j] + ": " + text + '</p>';
      } else {
        all_results += '<a href=' + text + " title=" + data.head.vars[j] + '>' + text + '</a>';
      }
      all_results += '</div>';
    }
    all_results += '</div>';
  }
  $('#result').html(all_results);

}

function doSparql() {
  var myEndPoint = "http://localhost:3030/Test/query";
  name = document.getElementById("search").value;
  var requiredName = "?Author foaf:firstName \"" + name + "\".}";

  myQuery = ["PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>",
    "PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>",
    "PREFIX locah: <http://data.archiveshub.ac.uk/def/>",
    "SELECT ?Register ?Id ?Date ?Type",
    "WHERE{",
    "?Register dcterms:creator ?Author.",
    "?Register dcterms:identifier ?Id.",
    "?Register dcterms:type ?Type.",
    "?Register locah:dateCreatedAccumulatedString ?Date.",
    requiredName
  ].join(" ");
  console.log('myQuery: ' + myQuery);
  window.alert(myQuery);

  $.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: myEndPoint,
    data: {
      "query": myQuery,
      "output": "json"
    },
    success: myCallBack2,
    error: myError
  });
  console.log('After .ajax');
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//raw.github.com/botmonster/jquery-bootpag/master/lib/jquery.bootpag.min.js"></script>

<div id="page-selection1" "></div>
<div id="result " class="result "></div>
<div id="page-selection2 "></div>

<script>
  $('#page-selection1,#page-selection2').bootpag({
    total: 50,
    page: 1,
    maxVisible: 5,
    leaps: true,
    firstLastUse: true,
    first: 'First',
    last: 'Last',
    wrapClass: 'pagination',
    activeClass: 'active',
    disabledClass: 'disabled',
    nextClass: 'next',
    prevClass: 'prev',
    lastClass: 'last',
    firstClass: 'first'
  }).on("page ", function(event, num) {
    $("#result ").html("Page " + num);

  });
</script>
```

I am expecting to show part of the results instead Page 1, Page 2... in #result according to a limit per page.

Comment: what do you mean by "it is not working"? Are there any errors being thrown? What are you seeing that is different from what you expect? And where is the backend code for your Ajax endpoint?

Comment: Are these copy and paste errors? `id="page-selection1""`